# Run a batch file silentily in NSIS

Tags: cmd, nsis

I have a batch file that needs to vbe excecuted, I am currently executing it using

```
Exec "$PLUGINSDIR\IISHelper.bat"
```

But while executing a black window is appearing which is not what is desired. I would like to run that batch file silently.
So I tried

```
Exec "start $PLUGINSDIR\IISHelper.bat /B"
```

But while this runs silently this doesn't have the elevated permission as it does for the installer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `start` would not be silent if it worked but it does not because start is not a program, it is a internal command in cmd.exe.

Use the nsExec plug-in (part of the default NSIS installation) to hide the console window.

```
nsExec::Exec '"$sysdir\cmd.exe" /c if 1==1 "$PLUGINSDIR\IISHelper.bat"'
Pop $0
```

Comment: Actually it worked with just 
nsExec::Exec /OEM "$PLUGINSDIR\IISStarter.bat"

Comment: Is there a way to do this asynchronously? Ironically, I want an nsExec::Exec that behaves like Exec and not ExecWait.

Comment: @KyleDelaney ExecShell with hidden display style.

Comment: @Anders Have you gotten ExecShell to hide the command window with batch files? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes

Comment: @Anders Actually I can't seem to get any of the show options to work with any kind of file. Do you know if there's some trick to it? Some setting that has to be set?